# CXF InInterceptor not firing what am I missing

Tags: java, apache, web-services, maven, cxf

Hello guys so I have all the code built with no errors but my Interceptor is not firing for some reason.. Can you help ?

My Service is coded like this :

```
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors(interceptors={"package.WSSecurityInterceptor"})
@WebService(name = "SERVICE", targetNamespace = "urn:some.namespace", serviceName = "SERVICE")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public class SampleService{ }
```

My Interceptor is coded like this:

```
public class WSSecurityInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

private String userName;
private String password;

public WSSecurityInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
}

public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

    System.out.println("WSSecurityInterceptor handleMessage invoked");
}
```

What am I missing ? I added the  to my jboss structure and on Maven I am calling dependencies on cxf 2.6.1. I can not see what I am missing.
Hope you guys can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the org.apache.cxf.impl dependency that I was missing, now everything works great !